# SendGrid's Event Webhook URL

Tags: twilio, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

**Problem**: How to make SendGrid's Event Webhook URL dynamic ?

**Issue**:

I have three environments where I listen for events from SendGrid email webhook. I want to listen to or track each email from this three env then I tried to use this /v3/user/webhooks/event/settings endpoint to make the URL dynamic. But, it does not work until I change it manually from the mail setting.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SendGrid user account can set one event webhook. If you are working with multiple environments, then I recommend you set up a [Subuser account](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/subusers) for each environment. A Subuser is owned by a user account, but has its own resources, including its own event webhook.

Comment: Thanks, @philnash. I will try that and let you know the result.

Comment: If it helped, please mark the answer as correct. That way others can see it helped too. Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that, one of the subuser account got  https://imgur.com/h5fNl23  disabled automatically. Please do you know why that is happening?

Comment: I don't know why that might have happened. Any problems like that with an account are best dealt with [by contacting SendGrid support](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us).